# "This account is currently not available" when running "cap deploy:setup" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I want to deploy Ruby on Rails web site and using Capistrano for this purpose.

After  I had filled in the deploy.rb file and ran `cap deploy:setup` this is what I got

```
C:\Sites\blog>cap deploy:setup
  * ←[32m2012-10-31 15:39:22 executing `deploy:setup'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "mkdir -p /var/www/blog /var/www/blog/releases /var/www/blog/
shared /var/www/blog/shared/system /var/www/blog/shared/log /var/www/blog/shared
/pids"←[0m
    servers: ["188.121.54.128"]
Password:
    [188.121.54.128] executing command
 ** [out :: 188.121.54.128] This account is currently not available.
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 153ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/blog /var/www/blog/releases /var/www/blog/shar
ed /var/www/blog/shared/system /var/www/blog/shared/log /var/www/blog/shared/pid
s'" on 188.121.54.128

C:\Sites\blog>
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Comment: check with your hosting provider and ask them why your account is currently not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot even log in into your remote server. Capistrano needs SSH access, so try to ssh in your server using the same credentials of the cap configuration, and you can't, contact your hosting provider to give you ssh access to the machine.

Comment: Yep, the SSH access wasn't configured on my server